# Can VANETs, MANETs, DTNs and others be simulated in NS-2 by using Windows?

Tags: windows, ns2, adhoc, dtn

Is this possible in Windows OS? If yes, what the steps are for start coding?

Comment: ns2 is a Linux application. You can install 'VirtualBox', and install one or more "Linux OS" into VirtualBox. ... All examples Vanet, Manet etc. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know the drill but I've heard `Cygwin command line interface` for Windows. As the information on the internet it can run NS-2, but I'm not sure that can implement VANETs, MANETs etc. So that I asked this question. If I gained detailed information about this, it would be better.. Thanks

Comment: ? Why use Cygwin, when it's easier to install a Genuine "Linux OS" ? ... And : A Linux OS will support all ns2 applications.

Comment: This is my choice.